Semi-continuity of Lelong number
Demailly gives the following some-continuity result for Lelong numbers:

Proposition. Let $T_k$ be a sequence of closed positive
currents of bidimension $(p, p)$ converging weakly to a limit $T$.
Suppose that there is a closed set A such that Supp $T_k \subset A$
for all $k$ and such that $\varphi$ is semi-exhaustive on $A$ with $A
> \cap B(R) \subset \subset X$. Then for all $r<R$ we have
$$
\begin{aligned} 
\int_{B(r)} T \wedge\left(d d^c \varphi\right)^p &
\leqslant \liminf _{k \rightarrow+\infty} \int_{B(r)} T_k
\wedge\left(d d^c \varphi\right)^p \\ & \leqslant \limsup _{k
\rightarrow+\infty} \int_{\bar{B}(r)} T_k \wedge\left(d d^c
\varphi\right)^p \leqslant \int_{\bar{B}(r)} T \wedge\left(d d^c
\varphi\right)^p . \end{aligned} 
$$
When $r$ tends to $-\infty$, we find in particular $$ \limsup _{k
 \rightarrow+\infty} \nu\left(T_k, \varphi\right) \leqslant \nu(T,
\varphi) \text {. } $$

The inequality above is verified through Demaily's proof, for the equality, we need to check $\limsup _{k
 \rightarrow+\infty}$ commutes with $\lim_{r\to 0}$, I don't know why. And I wonder when $\liminf _{k
 \rightarrow+\infty}$ commutes with $\lim_{r\to 0}$ so we can get $\liminf _{k
 \rightarrow+\infty} \nu\left(T_k, \varphi\right) \geqslant \nu(T,
\varphi)$ thus $\lim_{k\to +\infty}\nu(T_k,\phi)=\nu(T,\phi)$.
